# jQuery scrollTop() problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to achieve this:
qhen button is clicked, html is animated down to the "welcome" section and only then the overflow-y is visible (so that you can't scroll down from the header if not pressing the button). (That's the first script).
But i'm having problems with the second script. Basically is scrolls and fix the document at height 0px and can't scroll down. What i'm trying to achieve here is that if you scroll back from the welcome section, the html is animated up to the top of the page (returning everything at the initial state).

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    $(".scroll-icon").click(function() {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#welcome").offset().top
        }, 2000); 

        $("html").delay(200).queue(function (next) { 
            $(this).css({
                'overflow-y': 'visible'
            }); 
            next(); 
          });
    }); 

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var distance = $("#welcome").offset().top

          if ($(document).scrollTop() < distance) {
             $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top
             }, 2000);
          } 
    });


});
```

Here's a JsFiddle showing my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kp2yqyo8/6/

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I tried this:

```
// 1. Use a flag to check when you're welcome to the party!.
window.ImWelcome = false;

// 2. Your event click handler -- Same
$(".scroll-icon").click(function() {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#welcome").offset().top
    }, 2000); 

});  

// 3. Scroll handler...
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // 3.1 Store the values 
    var distance  = $("#welcome").offset().top
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    // 3.2 So..? Did you arrive to the party already ?
      if(scrollTop == distance){
        window.ImWelcome = true; // 3.2.1 Oh Yeah! 
      }

      // 3.3 Hmmm ... Seems like you want to leave huh? Ok let me take you to home
      if ($(document).scrollTop() < distance && window.ImWelcome) {
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top
         }, 2000);

         // Oh You're home and not welcomed 
         window.ImWelcome = false;
      } 

});
```

Now, talking seriously, the flag approach is simple. This used a global variable because it has to keep the state in the flag.

[JsFiddle here!](https://jsfiddle.net/kp2yqyo8/11/)

Comment: THANK YOU! you've been very kind, thanks for the incorporated explaination :)
I'm having another issue. The click event is only playing once. So once back on top, and the scroll icon is reclicked, nothing happens :\

Comment: I realized about a trouble when I posted the answer. Now I tested again and edited it @soldier

Comment: I can't tell how much i apprechiated your help! :) Everything worked fine. Thank you very much Jeancarlo :) (and i even learnt to use flags!)
Have a nice day